# Validation for custom type in Cerberus

Tags: validation, cerberus

I really enjoy Cerberus but I can't figure out a simple case in the docs. I want to have the type `fudge` which is a string with `~` prepended. I simply can't figure out how to do it..

```
fudge_type = cerberus.TypeDefinition('fudge_type', (str,), ())

class MyValidator(cerberus.Validator):
    types_mapping = cerberus.Validator.types_mapping.copy()
    types_mapping['fudge'] = fudge_type

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if 'additional_context' in kwargs:
            self.additional_context = kwargs['additional_context']
        super(MyValidator, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    @property
    def additional_context(self):
        self._error(field, "INVALID!")
        return self._config.get('additional_context', 'bar')

    def _validate_type_fudge(self, field, value):
        self._error(field, "INVALID!")
        make_use_of(self.additional_context)

validator = MyValidator()
validator.validate({'name': 'yada'}, {'name': {'type': 'fudge'}})  # => True
```

This seems like a simple case.. so it feels I am doing something totally wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Cerberus 1.2 you can achieve this like below:

```
import cerberus

SCHEMA = {
    'fudge': {
        'type': 'mytype'
    }
}

class MyValidator(cerberus.Validator):
    def _validate_type_mytype(self, value):
        if value.startswith('~'):
            return True

validator = MyValidator()
validator.validate({'fudge': 'yada'}, SCHEMA)
```

So no need to hack around with `TypeDefinition`.

Comment: So you in 1.2 you have to pass the SCEMA at the time of calling validate? Because I am trying to create custom type for `tuple` values. but it gives a run time error while accessing `_validate_type_tuple` method which is not there (even if I add that to my custom class.